# RAC tryMap alternative in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

What is the recommended approach in RxSwift to implement RAC `tryMap`-like functionality?

The following code is how I do mapping of json objects to an internal response wrapper class. If the response fails to comply with certain conditions, `nil` will be returned, which turns into an Error Event(tryMap implementation).

```
extension RACSignal{
    
    func mapToAPIResponse() -> RACSignal{
        return tryMap({ (object) -> AnyObject! in
            if let data = object as? [String:AnyObject]{
                //Some Logic
                return data["key"]
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
}
```

How should this be implemented in RxSwift?

### Updated-Possible Solution

I came up with following solution for Rx-Swift. Open for better solutions.

```
extension Observable{
    
    func mapToAPIResponse() -> Observable<APIResponse>{
        return map({ (object) in
            
            guard let dictionary = object as? [String:AnyObject] else{
                //APIResponseError.InvalidResponseFormat is defined in other class.
                throw APIResponseError.InvalidResponseFormat
            }
           
            
            let response = APIResponse()

            //Complete API Response
            return response

        })
}
```

My conclusion is to use throw inside a map to handle errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct, that's why `map` operator in RxSwift is annotated with `throws`. [Release notes of RxSwift 2](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxSwift/2.0.0/) explicitly state this:

> Adds support for Swift 2.0 error handling try/do/catch.
>
> You can now just write

```
API.fetchData(URL)
  .map { rawData in
      if invalidData(rawData) {
          throw myParsingError
      }

      ...

      return parsedData
  }
```

Even in `RxCocoa

Answer (score 0):

There is a great way to implement network layer with these set of PODs
[RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) + [Moya/RxSwift](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) + [Moya-ObjectMapper/RxSwift](http://Moya-ObjectMapper/RxSwift)

Finally your code for model will looks like

```
import ObjectMapper

final class Product: Mappable {
    var id: String?
    var categoryId: String?
    var name: String?

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        categoryId <- map["category_id"]
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

And for service

```
final class ProductService {

    class func productWithId(id: String, categoryId: String) -> Observable < Product > {
        return networkStubbedProvider
            .request(.Product(id, categoryId))
            .filterSuccessfulStatusAndRedirectCodes()
            .mapObject(Product)
    }
}
```

Comment: Noted on mapper framework. Question is about tryMap operator on RAC.